# Are there alternatives to nested LEFT JOIN's in VBA for Microsoft Access?

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access, vba

I am attempting to load a bajillion excel spreadsheets into a single, normalized database. My goal is to duplicate the structure of each original excel spreadsheet but convert the cell entries (the majority of which repeat frequently) into foreign keys before appending to a master table. I've found a process that ALMOST works but I'm running into some problems with an SQL query. I'm fairly savvy in VBA but quite new to databases and SQL, so while I'm confident I can dynamically generate the string necessary for a DoCmd.RunSQL, I'm having trouble with the query structure.

Here's what I'm trying to do:
After importing an excel spreadsheet into an Access table ("tbl_b"), I convert all entries in "tbl_b" to a corresponding foreign key before appending to another, preexisting table ("tbl_A").

For illustrative purposes, say the database contains the following tables:

**tbl_a**
field1_foreignKeys | field2_foreignKeys

**tbl_b**
field1_import | field2_import

**tbl_field1_primaryKeys**
field1_primaryKey | field1

**tbl_field2_primaryKeys**
field2_primaryKey | field2

I can successfully use the following query to achieve my goal:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_a (field1_foreignKeys, field2_foreignKeys)  
SELECT tbl_field1_primaryKeys.field1_primaryKey, tbl_field2_primaryKeys.field2_primaryKey  
FROM (tbl_B LEFT JOIN tbl_field1_primaryKeys ON tbl_b.field1_import = tbl_field1_primaryKeys.field1) LEFT JOIN tbl_field2_primaryKeys ON tbl_B.field2_import = tbl_field2_primaryKeys.field2
```

This works perfectly for an excel spreadsheet with two columns, but unfortunately, the spreadsheets I'm working with contain 26 columns, each of which must be converted to foreign keys before appending. Access is consistently crashing when I nest more than eight LEFT JOIN's, so I need a different solution. Hopefully this can be done and I'm missing something obvious :p

Any takers?
**........................................................................**

**UPDATE**

Regardless of whether or not I'm using the best data structure for my purposes (this database dilettante is optimistic), Don George's suggestion put me on the path to a working solution:

It occurred to me it was unnecessary to preserve "tbl_b" in its original condition, so I looped through each field with a dynamically generated version of the update query below:

```
UPDATE tbl_b LEFT JOIN tbl_field1_primaryKeys
ON tbl_b.field1_import = tbl_field1_primaryKeys.field1
SET tbl_B.field1_import = tbl_field1_primaryKeys.field1_primaryKey
```

After updating tbl_b I appended the whole thing to tbl_a all in one go.

Perhaps inelegant, but I thought I'd post my solution in case any other poor soul finds his/herself in an identical situation.

Comment: I think you might want to spend a little more time describing the data structure you have in mind and step us through an example Excel Sheet so we can see what you are trying to do because first thoughts for me are what exactly are you trying to accomplish (business case) and is that really the best data structure to get you want you want.....

Comment: I think I would set up a VBA loop to cycle through every field in the db and look the key up in the appropriate table.  You may also want to combine all of the foreign key tables into one table, with a field name, key and value.  That would simplify the VBA code.

Comment: In addition to the note above - I agree with Matt.  Normalization just to replace a text value with a number key, for example, seems overrated.  Is there something wrong with using the data as imported?  Once you replace the values with keys, won't you have a cumbersome problem trying to link back the 26 values when you want them?